# Unable to use associatedType as method returnType in swift as compiler throws "Ambiguous inference of associated type"

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui, generic-associated-types

Was playing with associatedType. Compiler is not recognising the return type of the method when using associatedType.

Here is the code sample,

```
protocol DummyOffice {
}

struct EmptyOffice: DummyOffice {
}

protocol  Office {
    associatedtype SubBranch: DummyOffice
    var subBranch: SubBranch { get }
    func getSubBranch() -> SubBranch
}

struct Apple: Office {
    let emptyOffice = EmptyOffice()
    func getSubBranch() -> some DummyOffice {
        return EmptyOffice()
    }
    
    var subBranch: some DummyOffice {
        return EmptyOffice()
    }
}
```

and compiler throws this error.

[image]

Questions:

(1) Error is not occurring for the property "subBranch". Thats is if I didn't create a method that returns associatedType in the protocol, everything works smooth.

Comment: Please don't post images, post text. And protocols and generics are two completely different things. Your code has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: @vadian, have updated the question with Code. 
Associated types are categorized under generics which is used within protocol https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Comment: Yeah so it seems that you can't make an opaque type an associated type as the compiler goes `'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions`

Comment: @zaitsman, as you suggested "typealias SubBranch =  DummyOffice" is working good.

Comment: @Sujananth o_O so can you post the entire code listing that works for you? because i tried that and the above is the error i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an opaque return type (i.e. `some`) is not required for what you want to do. When you go to implement the `Office` protocol, just return the *actual* type from the function and computed property you specified and the compiler will infer the `associatedtype` for you:

```swift
protocol DummyOffice {}

struct EmptyOffice: DummyOffice {}

protocol Office {
    associatedtype SubBranch: DummyOffice
    var subBranch: SubBranch { get }
    func getSubBranch() -> SubBranch
}

struct Apple: Office {
    let emptyOffice = EmptyOffice()
    func getSubBranch() -> EmptyOffice {
        return EmptyOffice()
    }
    
    var subBranch: EmptyOffice {
        return EmptyOffice()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Thanks. But it's weird that compiler is not throwing any error for the syntax with "some" if there is only a property and no methods declared.

Answer (score 0):

As @zaitsman suggested , replacing associatedTypes with typealias is working good.

[But typealias cannot be used as psuedo generic constraint,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622136/swift-what-is-the-difference-between-a-typealias-and-an-associatedtype-with-a-v)

```
protocol DummyOffice {
}

struct EmptyOffice: DummyOffice {
}

protocol  Office {
    typealias SubBranch =  DummyOffice
    var subBranch: SubBranch { get }
    func getSubBranch() -> SubBranch
}

struct Apple: Office {
    var subBranch: Self.SubBranch
    
    func getSubBranch() -> Self.SubBranch {
        return EmptyOffice()
    }
    
}
```